# How to remove the error message in magento2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, billing-address

I need to remove the error message in the magento2 billing address on the checkout page. How to remove that.

[image]

Comment: Image not shown properly

Comment: when billing address empty and click on update button this error is came

Comment: You can Refer to this article - https://www.interactiv4.com/blog-es-en/automatically-hide-messages-in-magento-2/?lang=en

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do here? magento requires a valid billing address to process a payment and proceed through checkout. whats your goal with this?

Comment: address field is required for you ? if not required you can remove address fields and avoid the Error required msg

Answer (score 0):

Find that line in the project with `grep -Ril "your text"` command and comment that for hiding the error on top for a quick solution or rewrite that file in your custom module and delete that line.